Bootstrap power analysis
Is power analysis through bootstrap sampling possible? Note, the desired output is MDE, not sample size. In context, assume sample size is fixed. We simply want to evaluate the smallest effect detectable.
If so, how is this accomplished? (python is preferred but R is also okay.)
The related Q/A can be summarized as "use caution" but is not actionable.
Edit: In my context, we have presence of extreme outliers. These outliers are very much of interest to the study. So we've developed a randomization algorithm, similar to stratification but based on quantiles. Additionally, we aim to use ANCOVA to mitigate any imbalance of this covariate's allocation to treatment vs control.
Because the randomization has already been executed, we cannot use power analysis calculators, which assume the same mean values, even if allowing for different variances.

Please edit the question to say more about your scenario. First, it's not clear whether this is for post-hoc power analysis for data that have already been collected (not generally a good idea; see this page) or for prospective study design. Second, if it's for prospective design, then it's not clear what data you would be bootstrapping; there might be a better simulation-based approach. Please edit the question to clarify, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

@EdM Context added!

Thanks for the addition. I'm still not clear on what data you will be bootstrapping from. Is it from a complete set of data that have already been collected, with no plans for further data collection and analysis? Or is this thus far a pilot study to guide planning? Please edit more to clarify. You should be warned that bootstrapping doesn't deal well with extremes of much of anything, as extremes in a population aren't typically represented well in any particular sample from which you might bootstrap. Simulation based on your understanding of the subject matter might be a better choice.
